# mathematica stop working after running some .nb file and close or save the file

Tags: bugs, front-end, crash, version-7

**Bug fixed in 8.0.4 for Chinese edition only, generally fixed in or before 11.3.**

---

I'm using version 7 on Windows.

After I running one `.nb` file and just want to close or save the `.nb` file, Mathematica stop working and the hints are as follows

```
Question signature: 
Problem event name: BEX64. 
Application name: Mathematica.exe. 
Application version: 7.0.18.33988. 
Application timestamp: 499cb2e1. 
Fault module name: Mathematica.exe. 
Fault module version: 7.0.18.33988. 
Fault module timestamp: 499cb2e1. 
Abnormal offset: 000000000042ec1e. 
Exception code: c0000409. 
Exception data: 0000000000000000
```

but in some other `.nb` files, after I run and close or save the file, there is no problem, maybe because this `.nb` file has some special codes？

but there are only the following codes that I think is special

```
approx = With[{k = 1000}, 1/Pi ArcTan[k #] + 1/2 &];
s1 = NDSolve[{Simplify`PWToUnitStep[equa00] /. UnitStep -> approx, 
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0} // SetPrecision[#, Infinity] &, 
  x, {t, 0, ts}, SolveDelayed -> True, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

and

```
paverage = 
 NIntegrate[p1, {t, 10, 10 + n*period}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100]/(n*period)
```

but what is the reason that it stop working?

and I have found that when I copy some `.nb` file to other file folder, when I paste it will appera 2 files, one is the same size with the origin file (I didn't verify whether the content is the same with the origin file), and another is one empty `.nb` file with the size of `0 kb`.

---

I have just found that in `version 7` it is because of your `file naming`, when your file name is too long and it can be named in `windows file` but can't be showed completed in mma, then if you just want to close or save the file, then it shows `stop working`.

For example, when the name is so long 试验台建模，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，2019.12.7，副本, it can't be shown completed in mma, when you want to close or save the file, it appears stop working.

Comment: the above code is from some nice man who helped me and I don't know how to @ you, If you see it, I hope you agree.

Comment: when i open the copied `.nb` file it appears,`Mathematica was unable to open the file`,`If you are trying to open this file from a web browser, try clearing your browser's cache before opening the file again or make a local copy of the file and try opening it from there. Error code = -43.`

Comment: You post a minimal working example reproducing the issue, or share the Notebook causing the crash. Are you using version 7.0 on Windows?

Comment: @Alexey Popkov,yes and it seems that it is because of the `File naming`.

Comment: You can add the link of your previous question from which you obtain the code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210294/1871 . And, it's better to mention you're using version 7 in the main body of the question, too.

Answer (score 1):

> for example,when the name is so long `试验台建模，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，自定义摩擦力，2019.12.7，副本`

I partially reproduce the issue with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64: *Mathematica* simply can't open a file with such name, and displays a "Why the Beep?" window (when trying to open the file via the `File ► Open...` menu item):

[image: screenshot2]

Note that an attempt to use the [short file name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143954/280) results in the same message.

When dropping the file from the Windows Explorer to the *Mathematica* 8.0.4 window using the mouse, another "Why the Beep?" window appears:

[image: screenshot2]

With *Mathematica* 11.3 and 12.0 both methods work correctly: *Mathematica* opens the file, displays its full name in the title of the window, and allows to edit and save edited file:

[image: screenshot3]

So the bug in handling Notebooks with such file names is fixed in the latest versions of the FrontEnd.

Comment: I guess you're testing in _v8.0.4_ English edition? Just tested in _v8.0.4_ Chinese edition, the file is opened without difficulty.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I use *Mathematica* 8.0.4 English edition.